# Howto gracefully shutdown mongod in `RoleEntryPoint.OnStop()` method

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, azure

I need to gracefully shutdown mongod.exe that is started with `System.Diagnostics.Process` in `RoleEntryPoint.OnStop()` method.

I was inspired by an article [Running MongoDb on Microsoft Windows Azure with CloudDrive](http://www.captaincodeman.com/2010/05/24/mongodb-azure-clouddrive/).
All seems to work fine, however after WorkerRole restart mongod says:

```
**************
old lock file: .\mongod.lock.  probably means unclean shutdown
recommend removing file and running --repair
see: http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for more information
*************
```

So I created simple *Console Application*, code below and simulated same result, when mongod.exe is killed. Lock file is released only when console window (parent process) is closed. Because of **CloudDrive is unmounted earlier than parent process is terminated** (`RoleEntryPoint`), mongod.lock file is never released in Windows Azure WorkerRole environment.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartMongo();

    Console.ReadLine();

    _mongoProcess.Close();
}

private static void StartMongo()
{
    _mongoProcess = new Process();
    var startInfo = _mongoProcess.StartInfo;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.FileName = @"mongod.exe";
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    startInfo.Arguments = "--dbpath .";

    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    _mongoProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, evt) => WriteLine(evt.Data);
    _mongoProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, evt) => WriteLine(evt.Data);

    _mongoProcess.Start();
    _mongoProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
    _mongoProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
}
```

How I realized that parent process is keeping the lock? I simply changed process to run in new shell window, where no output was redirected (`startInfo.UseShellExecute = true`). Two console windows started and when mongod was closed, it **released lock before main application was terminated**. I need to achieve this behavior to use it in `RoleEntryPoint` in Windows Azure.

Does anyone know how?

EDIT:

I realized, that maybe it's the parent process, that has the listeners to `ErrorDataReceived` and `OutputDataReceived` that holds proper closing/flushing of mongod output stream to mongod.lock ... can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `OnStop` method you can [**invoke the shutdown command**](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo#StartingandStoppingMongo-SendingshutdownServer%28%29messagefromthemongoshell). You could do something like

```
  var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://host:port");
  server.Shutdown();
```

If you are using the official 1.0 driver the shutdown command hangs even though it has shutdown the server. Azure will recycle this role instance in spite of the hang since you get only around 30 seconds in OnStop. This bug has been fixed in the latest version of the driver in GitHub https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver.

Additionally [**use mongodb 1.8.1 with journaling enabled**](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling#Journaling-Enabling). You would not need the repair then. This is needed if for some reason Azure recycles the role instance before the shutdown is completed and is not clean. More information on journaling can be found at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling

Comment: It seems that this would be the solution for my problem, however it isn't an answer.  I read that journal option will be the default in future releases, so I think I don't need to worry about this, do I? I hope that 4x writes for single insert won't kill my CloudDrive.

Comment: Even thought journaling is not the default now you can still use it. Add --journal to your process arguments alongwith --dbpath. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for adding the shutdown command, that one does exactly what is should (except the driver hanging issue, I will use fixed one from Github). I will enable journaling just to be sure and try to monitor performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Sridhar's answer, just to recapitulate and add some code for others as a reference.

**Starting the process** with journaling

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"--journal --dbpath c:\path\to\db";
```

**Shutting down** and then waiting 5 sec to process to exit. In my latest rev of the official mongo-csharp-driver it throws `EndOfStreamException` from `MongoDB.Driver.dll!MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage`. I hope this will be fixed soon.

```
    var t = new Task(() =>
    {
        var server = MongoServer.Create();
        //server.RunAdminCommand("shutdown"); -- throws exception
        server.Shutdown();
    });
    t.Start();

    try
    {
        t.Wait(5000);
    }
    catch (EndOfStreamException e)
    {
        // silently ignore
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!_mongoProcess.HasExited)
        {
            _mongoProcess.Kill();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: use `server.Shutdown()` instead of `server.RunAdminCommand("shutdown")`

Comment: When the server receives the shutdown command it closes the socket without replying. That's why the client sees an EndOfStreamException. I recommend you use the server.Shutdown() method instead of server.RunAdminCommand("shutdown") as it catches and ignores the EndOfStreamException for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do _mongoProcess.Kill() in OnStop()?

Comment: No. It doesn't write to lock file. I need to close it properly to release the lock, and as I found out, parent process listening to output needs to be closed as well.